# How can I make a pure javascript call to node.js which will update a dashboard via websockets

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, websocket

I currently have a client app that I want to keep as lightweight as possible using pure JavaScript.  I am sending an image request with a number of values in the query params.  For troubleshooting, I enable a flag and wish for this request to get sent to a server, currently thinking Node.js. I then want to have another webpage containing a dashboard that I open that makes a connection to this Node.js server via websockets.  When the request is fired from my pure JavaScript app, I would like to see the values appear on the dashboard. This will allow for me to perform some further processing on the values passed so I can more easily perform analysis.

Does anyone have any recommendations for this type of setup.  I currently have php I was calling on an Apache server and then was trying to setup ratchet to perform the websocket portion from the server, but after further reading, Apache and ratchet don't work well together.  I was having problems detecting the onOpen event and so many articles were recommending Node.js so I figured it was worth a look.

I have setup a Node.js server on AWS right now, but many of the tuts I have been finding are stating to use Socket.io from the cleints side or some other libs.  As stated above, I do not want to have any dependencies on the clients box, but don't care what I have to run on the server side.  If anyone with more experience in this area has any recommendations on a direction to go, I would love to hear it :)  Thanks so much for your time!

-- Edit --

In the end I setup node.js to handle the initial request with express.js. Then in the handler for this, I went about using socket.io to handle any updates of any other clients connected with the dash.  This seems to have worked as I wished.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. This question is much too broad as it stands.

Comment: Tried replying here but I guess it was too long so I had appended an edit above to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use websockets on the client side to achieve this,

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Websockets are not supported in older versions of IE,

http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets